# Python Application for Windows

Tags: python, windows, macos

I have a python Script which is running on Mac and I am able to convert it into a standalone application for Mac. Is there any way I can create a similar application for Windows ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this question was already answered many times. You can see in stackoverflow -> [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)